# NFS server not responding still trying

Tags: nfs

I've got two NetApp NFS shares which are mounted by each a single client. 
When copying files onto the shares the clients hang and in the "/var/log/messages" logfile "NFS server xxx not responding, still trying" followed by a "nfs server xxx OK" messages appear.

I already tried to only activate NFS v3 or v4 on Netapp, tried several other clients in different networks with serveral different mount-options. The shares worked for months now and after a short assessment of the config nothing has changed on the Netapp side.

For testing purposes I created on a client a NFS share and mounted it on another of the involved clients -> works fine.

I've attached some logs - maybe somebody can get more out of it than I do...

Thanks for any hint on this!

---

## EDIT:

There was indeed a layer8 problem:
We got of course a separate network for NFS communication. Although it was in this case possible to connect and use NFS connections over several other networks the traffic is obviously somewhere on some network components disrupted. Using the correct network solved the problem.

---

rpcdebug -m nfs -s all

```
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: FS-Cache: Loaded
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: RPC:       creating workqueue nfsiod
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs mount opts='vers=4.1,addr=10.1.66.1,clientaddr=10.1.31.69'
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'vers=4.1'
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'addr=10.1.66.1'
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'clientaddr=10.1.31.69'
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: MNTPATH: '/V_audit'
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: Key type dns_resolver registered
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: Key type id_resolver registered
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: Key type id_legacy registered
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs4_try_mount()
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs4_create_server()
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs4_init_server()
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs4_set_client()
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs_get_client(10.1.66.1,v4)
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: get client cookie (0xffff8aebe8ac9c00/0xffff8aebcef7d058)
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: nfs_create_rpc_client: cannot create RPC client. Error = -22
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: nfs_create_rpc_client: cannot create RPC client. Error = -93
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs_put_client({1})
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs_free_client(4)
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: releasing client cookie (0xffff8aebe8ac9c00/0xffff8aebcef7d058)
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: <-- nfs_free_client()
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: <-- nfs4_init_client() = xerror -93
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: <-- nfs4_set_client() = xerror -93
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: <-- nfs4_init_server() = -93
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs_free_server()
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: <-- nfs_free_server()
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: <-- nfs4_create_server() = error -93
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: <-- nfs4_try_mount() = -93 [error]
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs mount opts='vers=4.0,addr=10.1.66.1,clientaddr=10.1.31.69'
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'vers=4.0'
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'addr=10.1.66.1'
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:   parsing nfs mount option 'clientaddr=10.1.31.69'
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: MNTPATH: '/V_audit'
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs4_try_mount()
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs4_create_server()
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs4_init_server()
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs4_set_client()
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs_get_client(10.1.66.1,v4)
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: get client cookie (0xffff8aebe8ac9c00/0xffff8aebc0f90000)
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: nfs_create_rpc_client: cannot create RPC client. Error = -22
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: nfs_create_rpc_client: cannot create RPC client. Error = -93
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs_put_client({1})
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: --> nfs_free_client(4)
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: releasing client cookie (0xffff8aebe8ac9c00/0xffff8aebc0f90000)
Jul 26 09:33:41 ovirt-backup kernel: <-- nfs_free_client()
```

---

```
Jul 26 09:39:10 ovirt-backup systemd-logind: New session 6 of user root.
Jul 26 09:39:10 ovirt-backup systemd: Started Session 6 of user root.
Jul 26 09:39:10 ovirt-backup systemd: Starting Session 6 of user root.
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: permission(0:39/3560439872), mask=0x81, res=0
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: lookup(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS call  lookup vProtect-RHV.tar.gz
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:39/3560439872 fh_crc=0x0a5a63df ct=2 info=0x27e7f)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS reply lookup: -2
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: permission(0:39/3560439872), mask=0x3, res=0
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: create(0:39/3560439872), vProtect-RHV.tar.gz
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS call  create vProtect-RHV.tar.gz
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:39/3560439872 fh_crc=0x0a5a63df ct=2 info=0x7feff)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_fhget(0:39/3560458765 fh_crc=0x69886556 ct=1)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS reply create: 0
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: permission(0:39/3560458765), mask=0x20, res=0
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: open file(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: llseek file(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz, 0, 0)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz, 65536@0)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_begin(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@0)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_end(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@0)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz 4096@0)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage returns 0 (isize 4096)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_begin(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@4096)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_end(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@4096)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz 4096@4096)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage returns 0 (isize 8192)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_begin(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@8192)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_end(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@8192)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz 4096@8192)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage returns 0 (isize 12288)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_begin(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@12288)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_end(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@12288)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz 4096@12288)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage returns 0 (isize 16384)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_begin(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@16384)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_end(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@16384)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz 4096@16384)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage returns 0 (isize 20480)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_begin(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@20480)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_end(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@20480)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz 4096@20480)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage returns 0 (isize 24576)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_begin(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@24576)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_end(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@24576)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz 4096@24576)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage returns 0 (isize 28672)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_begin(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@28672)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_end(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@28672)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz 4096@28672)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage returns 0 (isize 32768)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_begin(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@32768)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_end(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@32768)
Jul 26 09:39:11 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz 4096@32768)
```

### ....

```
Jul 26 09:39:12 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_begin(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@17567744)
Jul 26 09:39:12 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_end(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@17567744)
Jul 26 09:39:12 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz 4096@17567744)
Jul 26 09:39:12 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage returns 0 (isize 17571840)
Jul 26 09:39:12 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_begin(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@17571840)
Jul 26 09:39:12 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: write_end(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz(3560458765), 4096@17571840)
Jul 26 09:39:12 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz 4096@17571840)
Jul 26 09:39:12 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS:       nfs_updatepage returns 0 (isize 17575936)
Jul 26 09:43:12 ovirt-backup kernel: nfs: server 10.1.66.1 not responding, still trying
Jul 26 09:43:12 ovirt-backup rsyslogd: imjournal: 2180749 messages lost due to rate-limiting
Jul 26 09:44:15 ovirt-backup kernel: nfs: server 10.1.66.1 not responding, still trying
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5977, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5976, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5975, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5974, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5973, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5972, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5971, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5970, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5969, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5968, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5967, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5966, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5965, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5964, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5963, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5962, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5961, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5960, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5959, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5958, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5957, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5956, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5955, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5954, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5953, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5952, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5951, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5950, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5949, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5948, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5947, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5946, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5945, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5944, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5943, (status 65536)
....
```

---

```
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  6232, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: nfs: server 10.1.66.1 OK
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  5978, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  6231, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  6190, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  6189, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  6219, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  6230, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  6229, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  6218, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS reply getattr: 0
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:39/3560439872 fh_crc=0x0a5a63df ct=2 info=0x27e7f)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: (0:39/3560439872) revalidation complete
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_weak_revalidate: inode 3560439872 is valid
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: revalidating (0:39/3560439872)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS call  getattr
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS reply access: 0
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: revalidating (0:39/3560439872)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS call  getattr
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_pgio_result:  6217, (status 65536)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:39/3560458765 fh_crc=0x69886556 ct=1 info=0x7febf)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: change_attr change on server for file 0:39/3560458765
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:39/3560439872 fh_crc=0x0a5a63df ct=2 info=0x27e7f)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS reply readdirplus: 676
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:39/3560458764 fh_crc=0xe95b37a9 ct=1 info=0x27e7f)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: change_attr change on server for file 0:39/3560458764
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: dentry_delete(/audit_STGT01-S014_last.xml, 40808cc)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_update_inode(0:39/3560458765 fh_crc=0x69886556 ct=1 info=0x27e7f)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: change_attr change on server for file 0:39/3560458765
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: isize change on server for file 0:39/3560458765 (2144600064 to 1864368128)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_do_filldir() filling ended @ cookie 4096; returning = 0
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: readdir(/) returns 0
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: permission(0:39/3560439872), mask=0x81, res=0
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_weak_revalidate: inode 3560439872 is valid
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: permission(0:39/3560439872), mask=0x81, res=0
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: permission(0:39/3560439872), mask=0x81, res=0
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_lookup_revalidate(/audit_STGT01-S014_last.xml) is valid
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: dentry_delete(/audit_STGT01-S014_last.xml, 40808cc)
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: permission(0:39/3560439872), mask=0x81, res=0
Jul 26 09:44:16 ovirt-backup kernel: NFS: nfs_lookup_revalidate(/vProtect-RHV.tar.gz) is valid
```

netstat -s

```
Ip:
    8570683 total packets received
    0 forwarded
    0 incoming packets discarded
    8566346 incoming packets delivered
    4090947 requests sent out
    7 outgoing packets dropped
Icmp:
    17 ICMP messages received
    0 input ICMP message failed.
    ICMP input histogram:
        destination unreachable: 17
    17 ICMP messages sent
    0 ICMP messages failed
    ICMP output histogram:
        destination unreachable: 17
IcmpMsg:
        InType3: 17
        OutType3: 17
Tcp:
    738 active connections openings
    380 passive connection openings
    0 failed connection attempts
    2 connection resets received
    24 connections established
    8565920 segments received
    4167196 segments send out
    389 segments retransmited
    0 bad segments received.
    23 resets sent
Udp:
    392 packets received
    17 packets to unknown port received.
    0 packet receive errors
    465 packets sent
    0 receive buffer errors
    0 send buffer errors
UdpLite:
TcpExt:
    8 invalid SYN cookies received
    394 packets pruned from receive queue because of socket buffer overrun
    363 TCP sockets finished time wait in fast timer
    1044 delayed acks sent
    Quick ack mode was activated 99852 times
    31152 packets directly queued to recvmsg prequeue.
    4 bytes directly in process context from backlog
    1791933 bytes directly received in process context from prequeue
    7097324 packet headers predicted
    540 packets header predicted and directly queued to user
    45043 acknowledgments not containing data payload received
    38888 predicted acknowledgments
    2 times recovered from packet loss by selective acknowledgements
    2 congestion windows recovered without slow start after partial ack
    7 fast retransmits
    343 other TCP timeouts
    TCPLossProbes: 1
    10994 packets collapsed in receive queue due to low socket buffer
    99852 DSACKs sent for old packets
```